# Regex to prevent repeated characters or numbers

Tags: swift, regex

```
static let password = "^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$"
```

I have this regex to validate password

- at least one character
- at least one Capital character
- at least one number
- length more than 8

I need to update it to

- prevent any repeated sequence of characters or numbers 
  to prevent "111111" or "aaaaaaa" for example
- to prevent starting and ending with space character

how to update my regex to match those requirements ?

Comment: Try `let password = "^(?=.{8})(?!.*([a-zA-Z\\d])\\1)(?=\\D*\\d)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])\\S.*\\S$"`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928791/regex-for-password-repetative-characters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768298/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-starting-with-or-ending-with-spaces

Comment: You know, to prevent spaces in the beginning and ending, I would evaluate putting a listener on the password field and, whenever it changes (char added), I would call a trim function. It could be an option to "reject the input" instead of refusing a whole password. Not sure it would be the best option though...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31954533/2303865